# How to find the shortest Selector

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, querypath

How can i get the shortest selector for any clicked element?
I want use this selector later to recover the same (or a nearly same) result.

Is there any existing method?

My ideas for that are searching with priority for:

1. single-used ID
2. multi-used ID with counter
3. single-used name
4. multi-used name with counter
5. single-used classname
6. multi-used classname with counter
7. shortest parent path to 1.-6.

Not shure how to build a short path for maximum reliability and maximum flexibility (f.e. new parent-tags or a movement in the code).

Comment: This heavily based on the structure of markup.

Comment: And you'll get vastly different results for a jQuery selector and a CSS selector...

Comment: I am working on a project that requires this. What i've come up with so far is to first have a Selector Precedence in mind. Here's the precedence I am woking with, 

`recurse each candidate element up the tree and check for selector with precedence  i.e Unique Attr > id > unique class > nth position` .

on each iteration check if the selector is unique , if so return it.

 I am stilll working on it and haven't completed it yet. But I will post when i feel my solution is stable.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like:

When an element is clicked

1. See if it has an ID, if so your selector is `#<id>`
2. If it does not have an ID, generate a random identifier and assign it as the element's ID, your selector is `#<generated-id>`

i.e. something like:

```
var selector = '';

$('element').click(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    if(!self.is('[id]')) {
        var id = 'ljhlihj'; // replace with code to generate random ID
        self.attr('id', id);
    }
    selector = '#' + self.attr('id');
}
```

Comment: good idea, but i want to use this on unknown foreign websites and i cant save anything on their code. (and want to use newest live-versions every time)